# ExecutorService control thread pools

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a pool of smartcards reader and I can use them to compute a digital signature.
This smartcard take a while to sign, so I need to setup a pool to queue requests and handle them as soon as possibile.

This is how I use a single smartcards:

```
try{
   Smartcard smartcard=new Smartcard(slot); //slot: reader number
   smartcard.sign(file);
}catch(SmartcardException e){
   throw e; //unusable smartcard
}
```

I thought to use ExcecutorService to manage multiple smartcards using a pool size equals to smartcard readers.
My doubt is if with this object I can attach a single reader to each thread, and moreover, if it can stop a single thread in case its smartcard fails with an SmartcardException (example: smartcard removed or broken).

I resume:

1. I have a pool of devices (smartcard readers) and I need an automatic system to manage the queue for their job.
2. In case of failure the device must be set as unusable and removed.
3. I want to achieve the smallest wait time for request.

Is ExcecutorService suitable?

Comment: `ExcecutorService` is abstract. You can’t say whether an `ExcecutorService` is suitable for your task if you don’t say *which* `ExcecutorService` you are talking about.

Comment: Yes of course, at the end I think no one of implementation of ExcecutorService are suitable... I need to build my own implementation connected to each device.

Answer (score 1):

The ExecutorService backs the submission with a `BlockingQueue`.  These queues are obviously FIFO and so by default the thread pool will execute as soon as possible for each request.

Comment: @Tobia how do you manage your `Smartcard`s?  Is there some kind of a lookup map you delegate to?  Something like  `smartcards.get(slot).sign(file);`?

Comment: Yes, I can define the slot in the constructor
new Smartcard(slot); or easily edith the sign method passing the slot in static sign(File file,int slot)...